# Synchronize secure vault in wso2 esb

Tags: wso2, esb

I have clustered and deployment synchronize enabled 'wso2 esbs'(4.9).and i had enable secure vault. now all the deployments have been sync with all worker nodes.but how can i sync my secure vault credentials with worker nodes.
I tried copy "wso2carbon.jks" file,i tried copy "cypher-text.property" file,it doesn't worked.
so how can i sync my secure valet with other worker node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you have clustered the environment correctly it should automatically get synchronized. Steps to follow,

1. Add a secure vault entry to ESB manager node.
2. Check the secure vaults in ESB woker node. (If not running in the -Dworker mode.)

If the workers are running on -Dworker mode, you can also check the wso2carbon.log for the logs right after adding the entries to secure vault.

Answer (score 1):

When you are deploying ESB cluster, you can use Puppet and Hiera to make the configurations changes.Wso2, already provided puppet modules to deploy wso2 product clusters.You can use existing Wso2 ESB puppet module to 
achieve your requirement. Refer "Running WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus with Secure Vault" section of the README of the [WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus Puppet Module](https://github.com/wso2/puppet-modules/tree/master/modules/wso2esb) to configure Secure Vault related configurations among the cluster.

Comment: Thank you. my problem was solved . it automatically synchronized with worker nodes after updating manager node .it is not necessary to adding secure vault credentials to worker nodes.